# A chat session about the direction of Buddhism SE

Tags: discussion, community

We are changing a lot as a site and I think it's fair to say that a number of users have concerns. Just in the way of a concrete suggestion - what about a chat room and a scheduled time span (perhaps over a weekend) where we can get together as a community and voice these concerns and perhaps focus our efforts in making this site a broad welcoming community (assuming that's what we want to be).

Anyone interested?

---

I think there is a reasonable consensus that an ongoing chat session about the site is a good idea. Here's what the live issues are for me but obviously all issues are up for discussion

1. Is our question policy too permissive. Should we be closing more questions down as opinion based, too broad etc...
2. Are comments being (mis)used as debates
3. Are we becoming less respectful of other's views. Is that an issue?

Anyway hope to see you in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism)

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a *very* good idea: and I look forward to re-reading it, reading what you say.

In fact, I am scheduled to be travelling: out of town this weekend, hours in a car, Saturday till Tuesday. I will only able to check in occasionally, if at all — but please, don't wait for me: start without me.

A well as "a scheduled time span" it's also possible to have a conversation which lasts a week, or which lasts indefinitely; people check-in occasionally when they have time (e.g. in the evening, once or twice a day, once or twice a week, whatever you can manage, or just keep a browser tab open during the day-time) read what's been said, reply, say a bit more, etc.

Comment: +1 for a conversation which lasts indefinitely :))

Comment: Well I'm [there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism) now.

Comment: I'll try to be there semi-permanently.

Comment: I'll try and join in as often as I can as well. +1 for a good idea.

Comment: +1 -- will join in and try to make some time to participate

Comment: I'm going to take this as a yes. Thanks all. I'm going to edit this question and put a featured tag on. I think just a chat starting now and progressing over the next few weeks it the best option.